# How to pass List<Int> to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have this user table type in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ListNew] AS TABLE
                               (
                                    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
                                    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
                               )
GO
```

And use this type in stored procedure parameter:

```
....
    (@lstNew ListNew READONLY,
     @UserName nvarchar(128))
AS
....
```

And using this stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC with this code:

```
List<int> lstNew = MyList.Select(o => o.Key).ToList();
List<XXXView> lstView = db.Database.SqlQuery<XXXView>("MyStoredProcedure @lstNew,@UserName",
              new SqlParameter("@lstNew", lstNew),
              new SqlParameter("@UserName", userName)).ToList();
```

but it's not working and get this error:

> No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to a known managed provider native type.

I try without ListNew and used only username, it's working

---

Edit:

I use this code:

```
myParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Udt;
myParameter.UdtTypeName = "ListNew";
```

But I get the same warning

Comment: This might help (both the code in the question and the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/q/32859133/1202807

Comment: @GabrielLuci: its not working for my, I edited my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pass a list to stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402296/can-i-pass-a-list-to-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

This is a solved problem and properly documented in - cough - the documentation.

YOu will need to define the table on the server side and then can pass in a table valued parameter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

This runs down to using the SqlDbType Structured.

```
// Configure the command and parameter.  
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, connection);  
SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpNewCategories", addedCategories);  
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  
tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.CategoryTableType";
```

You CAN use a DataTable, but then you introduce the most overhead approach possible as object model - or you just use...

https://forums.asp.net/t/1845039.aspx?Table+Value+Parameter+Use+With+C+without+using+DataTable

Basically you transform your data into SqlDataRecords and pass them in. Needs some metadata - but generally this can be generalized and fits in below a page of code. The link has the code (which I can not copy here due to - well - it not being MY code).

Answer (score 0):

I always use XML to pass these type of DATA to sqlserver sproc.

When you pass your XML to sproc you can use something like this to have it as a table in your sproc:

(commented lines are my XML's structure. manipulate it for your own use.)

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XmlHandle output,@FieldPermissionAccessXML
    --'<FieldPermissions>
    --<FieldPermission FieldName="" RoleID="1" Access="1" />
    --<FieldPermission FieldName="" RoleID="2" Access="1" />'
    --select * from JMP_FieldPermissions
INSERT INTO #FieldPermissionsTable 
SELECT *--ID,Value, Value2, Navi_User 
FROM  OPENXML (@XmlHandle, './Row_ID/Elements') 
      WITH (TE_ID VARCHAR(MAX) '@ID',
    Value VARCHAR(MAX) '@Value',
    Value2 VARCHAR(MAX) '@Value2',
    NAVI_USER VARCHAR(MAX) '@Navi_User'     
            )
```

Comment: And that is definitely the WORST way to do it, causing a lot of CPU usage both on the client but mostly on the server. Grats.

Answer (score 0):

Create the DataTable variable in c#, put the data in the DataTable, pass it to sp:

```
List<int> lstNew = MyList.Select(o => o.Key).ToList();
DataTable lstNewTable = new ListNew();
foreach (var id in lstNew )
{
    lstNewTable.Rows.Add(id);
}

List<XXXView> lstView = db.Database.SqlQuery<XXXView>("MyStoredProcedure @lstNew,@UserName",new SqlParameter("@lstNew", lstNewTable),
              new SqlParameter("@UserName", userName)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Several answers were close but none gave a full working model. @Alison Niu just needs to add a column & name to populate the DataTable. @Saurabh Gadani the reflection is very flexible but the Props are Null. Also the cmd.Parameters needs some special values set for Sql to find the table definition. I am grateful for these answers that got me closer to a solution.

Populate a DataTable from a List of Integers

```
    private DataTable ListInt_ToTable(List<int> tableThese)
    {
        DataTable lstNewTable = new DataTable();
        //Columns
        lstNewTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));

        //Values
        foreach (var id in tableThese)
        {
            lstNewTable.Rows.Add(id);   
        }
        return lstNewTable;
    }
```

The TYPE defines the table layout for SQL to receive the parameter. It can be written within the Stored Procedure but this is how I prefer to keep it in the application that built the data:

```
public static string SqlCmd_spStackOverflow_Loaded_ListIDs = @"
            IF TYPE_ID(N'IdLoadedTableType') IS NULL
                Begin
                    CREATE TYPE dbo.IdLoadedTableType
                       AS TABLE ( ID INT );
                End

            EXEC dbo.spStackOverflow_Loaded_ListIDs
                   @TblIds
    ";
```

Sending the Sql to run the Stored Procedure. Notice the parameters **

```
DataTable mappingTbl = ListInt_ToTable(mappingData);
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable results = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd_spStackOverflow_Loaded_ListIDs, sqlConnection);
                //apply parameters
                //NOT VIA sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(...);
                var specialParm = new SqlParameter();    // **
                specialParm.ParameterName = "@TblIds";   // acts like a Declare in SQL
                specialParm.Value = (object)mappingTbl;  // sets the data valaes                                                           
                specialParm.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured; // unique to User-Defined Table parameters
                specialParm.TypeName = "dbo.IdLoadedTableType"; // refers to created type
                sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(specialParm); // done

                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(results);
                return results;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("An error occurred while executing a SQL Read statement with Parameters. SQL Statement: " + SqlCmd_spStackOverflow_Loaded_ListIDs + " Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This model is working in my solution, except I use long in C# & BigInt in sql. Please improve options as you find something.

Answer (score -1):

You can not pass any generic type list as SP parameter, must have to pass it as DataTable instead of List.
Here is an eaxample:

```
DataTable mappingTbl = ListToDataTable(mappingData);

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedure.GetSavedFormList, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UDT_EBFromMappingTable", mappingTbl);


public DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

            //Get all the properties
            PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
            {
                //Defining type of data column gives proper data table 
                var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);
                //Setting column names as Property names
                dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
            }

            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[Props.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {
                    //inserting property values to datatable rows
                    values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
            return dataTable;
        }
```

May this helps you. :)